# How to do IP address rate limiting in docker?

Tags: nginx, docker, fail2ban, rate-limiting

I have a docker webapp running, port mapped to a machine-running nginx server, and fail2ban to do rate limiting.

Unfortunately, when viewing netstat, docker looks like its using all internal IPs (things like `localhost:59719`), rather than exposing through the external IP requests, so the nginx and fail2ban rate limits have no effect.

Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to rate limit on source IP is to not use NATs or proxies. Possibly overly simplistic, as sometimes a proxy is necessary for an application; there are more ways of doing container networking.

A static addressed [IPv6 configuration I modified slightly from Michael Stapelberg's blog](https://michael.stapelberg.ch/posts/2018-12-12-docker-ipv6/): 
Add to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:13b:330::/64"
}
```

Create networks and statically addressed containers.

```
docker network create --subnet 2001:db8:13b:330::/64 --ipv6 nginx

docker run \
  --network nginx \
  --ip6 2001:db8:13b:330:ff::80 \
  --publish 203.0.113.1:80:80 \
  nginx
```